# User groups in Linux

Tags: linux, groups

Something is wrong. I've a user U which has primary group A and secondary B.

Folder /www/dev is now 775 and set to user www-data and group B

But my user U does not have writing permissions to that folder, am I missing something here?

-- 06.51pm: Permissions are drwxrwxr-x

Comment: Can you run `ls -ld /www /www/dev` and edit your post and add the output?

Comment: Type `id U` (substitute the real userid for U) and compare the group ids that come up to the group on /www/dev/.  Do a `ls -lnd /www/dev` to see the numeric group id on the directory.

Comment: Check that this is not an SELinux or an AppArmor problem. Either of those could be preventing access where the traditional unix permissions bits would otherwise allow.

Answer (score 1):

After adding user `U` to group `B`, `U` must logout and log back in to take effect.

Comment: Also note that unless you specify `-R` permission changes are not recursive, and that if your webserver is writing stuff to that directory it may muck up your permissions (check the umask the webserver runs with)...

Answer (score 0):

Did you unpack something as root? `tar` is preserving the UIDs when run as root.

Comment: The folder is empty, I was just testing the permissions.
I can provide some more information if needed, just not sure what's needed